# VIM: Browse for symbol? how?

Tags: c++, linux, vim, fuzzyfinder

I've looked in several plugins (FuzzyFinder/YouCompleteMe/Command-T/ctags) and they all give me almost what I want... and I'm sure it's in one of them and I cannot find it..

I want is a drop down menu (like command-t.. fuzzyfinder) so I can grep for a specific symbol (even generated by ctags).
For example look for class Worker and it would give me all symbols that contain Worker in them.. (functions even etc..)

Anyone?
even using YCM's GoToDefenition would work if I could give it input..

Thanks.

Comment: Try [clang-complete](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3302).

Answer (score 8):

- FuzzyFinder: [`:FufTag`](https://bitbucket.org/ns9tks/vim-fuzzyfinder/src/4014e500fb8d90e4906fb63b500c67dab92fdd9e/doc/fuf.txt?at=default#cl-264)
- Command-T: [`:CommandTTag`](https://github.com/wincent/command-t/blob/master/doc/command-t.txt#L491)
- There's also CtrlP, if you want: [`:CtrlPTag`](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim/blob/master/doc/ctrlp.txt#L1067)
- YouCompleteMe: [`:YcmCompleter GoToDefinition`](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/blob/master/doc/youcompleteme.txt#L772-L796)

`:help tags` and `:help ctags` tell you everything you need to know about tags in general and ctags in partular. Which is already a lot, without messing with plugins:

```
:tag Worker
```